# How to load a workflow into rehosted WorkflowDesigner in a background thread?

Tags: wpf, multithreading, threadpool, workflow-foundation-4

We have a tool that rehosts the WorkflowDesigner of .NET 4.0.1. We are loading quite heavy workflows into it, it **takes up to 15 seconds** to finish the **WorkflowDesigner.Load()** method. All this is done in the UI thread, which freezes display and prevents user from interacting.

So I would like to prepare the WorkflowDesigner in a background thread, and as soon as it is ready for display, I would like to swap it into my view.

I'm running into the well known problems that UI objects cannot be created or manipulated from a non-UI-thread. Yet, locking the application for 15 seconds is a no-go.

Is there any workaround to do the loading and keep the UI responsive?
(We can not switch to .NET 4.5.1 at the moment, if that makes a difference at all..)

What I tried so far is

```
            Thread thread = new Thread(() => LoadWorkflowDesigner());
            thread.Name = "WorkflowDesignerLoader";
            thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
            thread.Start();
```

and in the created thread

```
    [STAThread]
    private void LoadWorkflowDesigner()
    {
            WorkflowDesigner tmpDesigner = new WorkflowDesigner();
            tmpDesigner.Load(WorkflowPath);
            this.WorkflowDesignerView = tmpDesigner;
            RaisePropertyChanged(() => WorkflowDesignerView);
```

This way creation does work, but databinding from the view after the RaisePropertyChanged will throw the exception :(

Comment: Not possible.  You need to leverage virtualization in the designer UI (hopefully you wrote those) to ease loading time.

Comment: The workflow designer itself is by Microsoft, we are only hosting it in our UI. It's a complex control. And as it has no async API, I guess I'm out of luck...? (Not sure what exactly you mean with "virtualization in the designer UI")

Comment: The designer, and the designers for each workflow component are two different things.  You can create your own workflow components that have their own designers.  If you have lots of these being loaded, and they aren't designed well (don't take advantage of virtualization), you can encounter your situation.  If this is all straight-up MS, then you are limited to what you can do.  All UI components are thread-centric, so you can't load them on a different thread...

Comment: Ok, you are talking about the individual activity designer. Well, that#s a mix. In my specific workflow, I see 212 activities that we designed ourselves (all have CacheMetadata implemented, so I see the calls to that method). Other than that, there are around 300 MS activities in the workflow. What exactly could I do in our own designers? The time spent in our own methods during loading is neglectable according to my traces...

Comment: That big?  Nope, not much you can do about it.  But make sure your UI isn't doing anything unnecessarily.  Your standard tuts and docs about creating fast WPF applications apply here.

Answer (score -1):

Could you create a WorkflowDesigner at the UI level then use your code to create and load a new 2nd WorkflowDesigner off the UI thread.
Then when the 2nd WorkflowDesigner is ready you make the 1st WorkflowDesigner = to the 2nd WorkflowDesigner.  By a call back I would think.

The loaded WorkflowDesigner is now in the UI thread and you can run RaisePropertyChanged

Comment: But as soon as interaction happens, it crashes because the designer internals were not created in the UI thread :(